# How to show blank record in table using JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have one JSON file. I have to read JSON file in this file WinType is field in that field two value Nominated and Win. I have to arrange this value into table as in 1 = Win and 0 = Nominated. But some time if record not found in json file that time i want `<td> </td>` blank. So my table is shows as follows

```
<html>
<body>
    <TABLE BORDER=2 BORDERCOLOR=RED> 
        <TR> 
            <TD>12 Years a Slave</TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>

        <TR> 
            <TD>American Hustle</TD>
            <TD>0</TD>
            <TD>0</TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
        </TR> 

        <TR> 
            <TD>Captain Phillips</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD>0</TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

My JSON file is:

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
    "Nominee": "12 Years a Slave",
    "WinProbability": 0.00,
    "WinType": "Win"
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Nominee": "12 Years a Slave",
    "WinProbability": 0.66,
    "WinType": "Nominated"
}, {
    "ID": 1,
    "Nominee": "American Hustle",
    "WinProbability": 1.62,
    "WinType": "Nominated"
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Nominee": "American Hustle",
    "WinProbability": 0.85,
    "WinType": "Win"
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Nominee": "American Hustle",
    "WinProbability": 0.07,
    "WinType": "Win"
}, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Nominee": "Captain Phillips",
    "WinProbability": 0.00,
    "WinType": "Win"
}, {
    "ID": 3,
    "Nominee": "Captain Phillips",
    "WinProbability": 1.52,
    "WinType": "Win"
}]
```

I tried to but not working properly.

Tried code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'movie.json',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data) {
        var groupByNominee = data.reduce(function(rv, x) {
            (rv[x['Nominee']] = rv[x['Nominee']] || []).push(x);
            return rv;
        }, {});

        $(Object.keys(groupByNominee).map((nom) => 
            `<TR>
                <TD>${nom}</TD>
                ${groupByNominee[nom].map((item)=>
                        `<TD>
                            ${(item.WinType==='Win')?1:0}
                        </TD>`
                    ).join('')
                }

            </TR>`
            ).join('')).appendTo('#Table');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by record not found? Are you talking about a missing attribute? The sample JSON you posted doesn't appear to be missing anything that would result in the blank condition you are seeking.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson if attribute is missing in table td blank

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson in my tried code compare Nominee but not match ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just are just potentially missing WinType attribute, try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'movie.json',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data) {
        var groupByNominee = data.reduce(function(rv, x) {
            (rv[x['Nominee']] = rv[x['Nominee']] || []).push(x);
            return rv;
        }, {});

        $(Object.keys(groupByNominee).map((nom) => 
            `<TR>
                <TD>${nom}</TD>
                ${groupByNominee[nom].map((item)=>
                        `<TD>
                            ${(typeof(item.WinType) !== 'undefined' && item.WinType.length > 0) ? (item.WinType === 'Win' ? '1' : '0') : ''}
                        </TD>`
                    ).join('')
                }

            </TR>`
            ).join('')).appendTo('#Table');
    }
});
```

This should check the WinType attribute is present and it's length (if found) is greater than 0 before checking if it's equal to Win.

Comment: if "Nominee": "12 Years a Slave" is ID = 2 is not found in json file then my tr look like this <tr><td>1</td><td></td><td>0</td></tr>

Comment: I don't get it. It shows in your JSON two entries for 12 years a slave and they both have WinType values

Comment: yes but in American hustle have 3 ID and 12 slave only 2 ID so one ID is missing so in tr one td should be blank

Comment: ID is usually for unique identifiers, are you saying that there has to be 3 entries in order for it to qualify for having a wintype? The structure of your data seems to be off.

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON? If so, I would restructure it. I would do that for you, but I don't understand what the data represents. Why would there be multiple entries for a single movie, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
Nominee            "ID":1   "ID":2  "ID":3
12 Years a Slave    1                 0
American Hustle     0         1      1
Captain Phillips              1      1
```

Then you need a reference group, such as [1,2,3]
This code just to show the missing part, not elegant, but works:

```
function (data){
  var groupByNominee=data.reduce(function(rv, x) {
     (rv[x['Nominee']] = rv[x['Nominee']] || []).push(x);
     return rv;
  }, {});
  var ids = [1,2,3];


   $(Object.keys(groupByNominee).map((nom)=>{
     var str = '<TR>';
     str += '<TD>'+    nom + '</TD>'

     var ids=[1,2,3]; //Need all IDs 
     var mid = ids.map((id)=>{ // then loop all ids to get the empty id displayed.
       var type = "";
       groupByNominee[nom].forEach((item)=>{
         if (item.ID == id){
           type = (item.WinType==='Win')?'1':'0' ;
         }
        });
        return '<td>'+type+'</td>';
     }).join('');
     str += mid;
     str += '</TR>';
    return str; 
   }
   ).join('')).appendTo('#Table');

}
```